# Связь html формы с моделью Django

Tags: python, html, django, form, model

Есть модель:

```
class Order(models.Model):


f_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
l_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
company = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=20)
country = models.CharField(max_length=20)
adress = models.CharField(max_length=20)
zip = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=40)
province = models.CharField(max_length=40)
phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
email = models.EmailField()
```

Как сделать форму в шаблоне html, чтобы **html** проверял правильность ввода?

Код ниже производит проверку на уровне backend'a, у меня в html шаблоне уже есть форма с каждым пунктом по-отдельности, но не могу связать в таком случае с моделью.

```
   <form action="." method="post" class="order-form">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Place order"></p>
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

Форма, которая у меня уже есть в html:

```html
    <!-- Checkout -->
    
    <div class="checkout">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <!-- Billing Info -->
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="billing checkout_section">
                        <div class="section_title">Billing Address</div>
                        <div class="section_subtitle">Enter your address info</div>
                        <div class="checkout_form_container">
                            <form action="#" id="checkout_form" class="checkout_form">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xl-6">
                                        <!-- Name -->
                                        <label for="checkout_name">First Name*</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="checkout_name" class="checkout_input" required="required">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xl-6 last_name_col">
                                        <!-- Last Name -->
                                        <label for="checkout_last_name">Last Name*</label>
                                        <input type="text" id="checkout_last_name" class="checkout_input" required="required">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <!-- Company -->
                                    <label for="checkout_company">Company</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="checkout_company" class="checkout_input">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <!-- Country -->
                                    <label for="checkout_country">Country*</label>
                                    <select name="checkout_country" id="checkout_country" class="dropdown_item_select checkout_input" require="required">
                                        <option></option>
                                        <option>Russia</option>
                                        <option>Belarus</option>
                                        <option>Ukraine</option>
                                        <option>Kazakhstan</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <!-- Address -->
                                    <label for="checkout_address">Address*</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="checkout_address" class="checkout_input" required="required">
                                    <input type="text" id="checkout_address_2" class="checkout_input checkout_address_2" required="required">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <!-- Zipcode -->
                                    <label for="checkout_zipcode">Zipcode*</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="checkout_zipcode" class="checkout_input" required="required">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <!-- City / Town -->
                                    <label for="checkout_city">City/Town*</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="checkout_city" class="checkout_input" required="required">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <!-- Province -->
                                    <label for="checkout_province">Province*</label>
                                    <input type="text" id="checkout_province" class="checkout_input" required="required">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <!-- Phone no -->
                                    <label for="checkout_phone">Phone number*</label>
                                    <input type="phone" id="checkout_phone" class="checkout_input" required="required">
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <!-- Email -->
                                    <label for="checkout_email">Email Address*</label>
                                    <input type="email" id="checkout_email" class="checkout_input" required="required">
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkout_extra">
                                    <div>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_terms" name="regular_checkbox" class="regular_checkbox" checked="checked">
                                        <label for="checkbox_terms"><img src="{% static 'frontend/images/check.png' %}" alt=""></label>
                                        <span class="checkbox_title">Terms and conditions</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_newsletter" name="regular_checkbox" class="regular_checkbox">
                                        <label for="checkbox_newsletter"><img src="{% static 'frontend/images/check.png' %}" alt=""></label>
                                        <span class="checkbox_title">Subscribe to our newsletter</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался.
Все делает банально просто, в классе Meta класса формы можно передавать формам атрибуты html классов, id и т.д.
В итоге forms.py выглядит сейчас так:

```
class CheckoutForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Order
    fields = ['f_name', 'l_name', 'company', 'country', 'adress', 'zip',
              'city', 'province', 'phone', 'email']

    widgets = {
        'f_name': TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'checkout_input',
            'id': 'checkout_name'

        }),
        'l_name': TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'checkout_input',
            'id': 'checkout_last_name'

        }),
        'company': TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'checkout_input',
            'id': 'checkout_company'

        }),
        'country': TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'checkout_input',
            'id': 'checkout_country'

        }),
### и т.д. каждый пункт модели ####
    }
```

В html выводил каждый пункт формы по-отдельности:

```
{{ checkout_form.f_name }}
{{ checkout_form.l_name }}
```

и т.д.